# Mongolian DeadBeef .toArray() returns _id in unexpected format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I love mongogolian deadbeef but I'm stumped. I'd like to get the results of a simple .find() to return in the same JSON format which matches the output of Mongo's command line:

```
$ db.mycollection.find();
# outputs..
# { ...some data... , "_id" : ObjectId("4f0b371c0000008b6d000008") }
```

However with deedbeef, the .find() method does not return a result or provide a callback. 
So I've been using .toArray(); which seems right to me.

```
Mongolian = require("mongolian"),
server = new Mongolian,
db = server.db("mydatabase"),
mycollection = db.collection("mycollection"),

mycollection.find().toArray(function(err, data){
   res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
});

// outputs..
// { ...some data... ,  _id: { bytes: <Buffer 4f 0b 61 5a 00 00 00 7e 6e 00 00 06> } }
```

Stingifying the _id binary (I assume that is what the buffer is) is resulting in a metric @#$! ton of data. What is the correct way to return JSON from mycollection.find() ?

~~~~~~~

I've been able to strip the _id from the results using the follow:

```
 mycollection.find({}, { id:0 }).toArray(function(err, data){
   res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

However the larger issue of how to deal with converting _id from JSON to BSON still remains.

Comment: just to ask the dumb questions, deedbeef.find in the second paragraph should be deadbeef right? Typos are the worst rubber duck error

Comment: @Asa - got the same here - looks like at least 10 metric @#$! tons to me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 'data' is an array of document objects, but not all of the data has a format that is compatible with JSON.

Look here: https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian
in the BSON Data Types section.

It looks like your document has a 'ObjectId' type, so you either need to remove the ObjectId data before converting to JSON, or you need to convert the data into a format that works.

Comment: The only reference I could find to BSON was in (https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian/blob/master/lib/cursor.js). Am I looking in the wrong place? 

The ObjectId is set automatically by a very simple save function
`mycollection.save( { "foo" : "bar" } );` 

I would have thought that by allowing mongo to create the _id, then that _id would be JSON compatible with requiring the result of a query to be parsed.

Comment: Yeah, the BSON logic is all handled by node-buffalo. The code for ObjectID is here: https://github.com/marcello3d/node-buffalo/blob/master/lib/objectid.js I think you may just need to do data[...]['_id'].toString() on each record to convert it to hex before you convert to JSON.

Comment: Yikes, what does that meen for update operations? How will I be able to reconvert the _id string back into BSON?

Comment: I guess you'll have to convert back the other direction. `new Mongolian.ObjectId(hex_string)`. I haven't really used Mongolian, so I can't really suggest more than that.

Comment: Thanks Logan you've been very helpful.

Comment: It seems very strange to be that a DB driver would not properly support the native id type of the database...

Comment: For details on converting Mongo's ObjectID to a string and some examples please see: https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian/issues/76